# Add Watermark with AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInput

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

Is here a way to add watermark to the frames being written by avassetwriter?

Based on what I've googled they are all assuming that the video was already created. What if the video is not yet created before it is created is should already have a watermark. Would that be possible?

Thanks

Comment: ever find the answer?

Comment: Did you find the answer?